# PyTorch: Vectorizing patch selection from a batch of images

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, torchvision

Suppose I have a batch of images as a tensor, for example:

```
images = torch.zeros(64, 3, 1024, 1024)
```

Now, I want to select a patch from each of those images. All the patches are of the same size, but have different starting positions for each image in the batch.

```
size_x = 100
size_y = 100
start_x = torch.zeros(64)
start_y = torch.zeros(64)
```

I can achieve the desired result like that:

```
result = []
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    result.append(arr[i, :, start_x[i]:start_x[i]+size_x, start_y[i]:start_y[i]+size_y])
result = torch.stack(result, dim=0)
```

The question is -- is it possible to do the same thing faster, without a loop? Perhaps there is some form of advanced indexing, or a PyTorch function that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `torch.take` to get rid of a for loop. But first, an array of indices should be created with this function

```
def convert_inds(img_a,img_b,patch_a,patch_b,start_x,start_y):
    
    all_patches = np.zeros((len(start_x),3,patch_a,patch_b))
    
    patch_src = np.zeros((patch_a,patch_b))
    inds_src = np.arange(patch_b)
    patch_src[:] = inds_src
    for ind,info in enumerate(zip(start_x,start_y)):
        
        x,y = info
        if x + patch_a + 1 > img_a: return False
        if y + patch_b + 1 > img_b: return False
        start_ind = img_b * x + y
        end_ind = img_b * (x + patch_a -1) + y
        col_src = np.linspace(start_ind,end_ind,patch_b)[:,None]
        all_patches[ind,:] = patch_src + col_src
        
    return all_patches.astype(np.int)
```

As you can see, this function essentially creates the indices for each patch you want to slice. With this function, the problem can be easily solved by

```
size_x = 100
size_y = 100
start_x = torch.zeros(64)
start_y = torch.zeros(64)

images = torch.zeros(64, 3, 1024, 1024)
selected_inds = convert_inds(1024,1024,100,100,start_x,start_y)
selected_inds = torch.tensor(selected_inds)
res = torch.take(images,selected_inds)
```

---

**UPDATE**

OP's observation is correct, the approach above is not faster than a naive approach. In order to avoid building indices every time, here is another solution based on `unfold`

First, build a tensor of all the possible patches

```
# create all possible patches
all_patches = images.unfold(2,size_x,1).unfold(3,size_y,1)
```

Then, slice the desired patches from `all_patches`

```
img_ind = torch.arange(images.shape[0])
selected_patches = all_patches[img_ind,:,start_x,start_y,:,:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my aim was to make the code faster (presumably by eliminating the loop), not just get rid of the loop per se. Since your solution requires building indices every time one wants to select patches with a new set of patch positions, I don't think it is going to be faster than the naive solution.

Comment: @DLunin You're welcome :) Your observation is correct, I updated my post with a solution using `unfold`, the idea is to create a tensor of all possible patches in the first place, then slicing it directly with `start_x` and `start_y`.